# PyQt5 QWebEngineView causes the whole window to go white/blank

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I have this weird problem on Windows 10 with PyQt5 QWebEngineView.
[image]
When I delete `self.webView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self.groupBox_4)` from `window_ui.py` which is generated with `pyuic5` app starts fine. When I add it back, whole window is just white.
However, my Windows 10 in VirtualBox works just fine. Also works in Ubuntu, but I had to install pyqt and pyqtwebengine from apt repositories because of import errors.
Also, when hovering on invisible textboxes cursor will change, and I can click on invisible buttons and they will work.

QT Versions are always:

```
pyqtwebengine 5.15.6   
pyqt5 5.15.4
```

A quick summary of the environments tested:

| Device | Python Version | EXE/PY file | Result | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Physical | 3.10.4 | PY file | Works | - |
| Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Physical | 3.9.5 | EXE with Wine | Works | - |
| VirtualBox Windows 10 under Ubuntu 22.04 | 3.9.5 | PY file | Works | Compiled exe with pyinstaller on this machine |
| VirtualBox Windows 10 under Ubuntu 22.04 | 3.9.5 | EXE file | Works | - |
| Remote VDS Windows 10 | 3.9.5 | EXE file | Does not work | - |
| Remote VDS Windows 10 | 3.10.5 | PY file | Does not work | not initializing QWebEngineView solves the issue |
| Physical Windows 10 #1 | 3.9.5 | EXE file | Does not work | - |
| Physical Windows 10 #2 | 3.9.5 | EXE file | Does not work | - |

There are no errors or any logs. Any ideas to further troubleshoot this?

p.s. I can see the qwebengineview does load properly, because I'm getting logs from javascript on my html page. I've also tested just initializing the window and objects, no connects, no functions except basics like showing the window etc. and there's the same problem.

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, the problem *only* happens on regular (not virtualized) Windows 10, and only with Python 3.10, while it works fine *on the same system* with Python 3.9?

Comment: @musicamante I'm not sure if virtualization is relevant. Pyinstaller exe containing 3.9.5 python has been tested under 2 physical computers and 1 VDS, it does not work. On the same VDS, Python 3.10.5 running .py files directly do not work. VM with Python 3.9.5 .py files work, and exe file generated on same VM also work. The exe file on Ubuntu with wine also works. I'll edit to clarify

Comment: Oh, so the *real* issue is with VDS. I'm not familiar with the technology, and you didn't specify the virtualization system (VirtualBox? VMWare?), but consider that QtWebEngine tries to use OpenGL for rendering, which might be a problem in screenless systems that don't normally use such aspects. Try looking for ways to force software rendering, starting with [this](//stackoverflow.com/q/33090346) and [this](//stackoverflow.com/q/35747995). For future reference, please take more time in providing *all* important details: when you mention "VM" we normally assume it's a desktop virtualization.

Comment: @musicamante well, I don't think so, since trying on a physical machine also has the same issue. My VirtualBox VM under Ubuntu 22.04 does work. VDS does not work. Physical computers do not work. Maybe they are also having issues with OpenGL. sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but I will check the related OpenGL questions, thanks!

Comment: Ok, please try to put the different cases in order, as they're a bit confusing: consider using a table and clearly separate working configurations from the others.

Comment: @musicamante setting env variable QT_OPENGL=angle worked wonders! would you like to post an answer, so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 4):

export QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--no-sandbox"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have seen many answers to the problem of a blank QWebEngineView in PyQt5 and this is the only one that actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours and hours looking into this, with many solutions very similar to this talking about Chromium bug / GPU / shared memory, such https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/22775#issuecomment-616023334 to use `--no-xshm` or `QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1` or `docker run --ipc=host`.

This is the only thing that worked, and it was very hard to find.

In my case I was trying to run `openconnect-sso` in a docker container with x11 forwarding, so that the two factor (2FA) / multi factor (MFA) login popup with Duo for the Cisco Anyconnect VPN client could be run and routed in a minimal container.

Many thanks!

Going to add links back to this for anyone who runs into this issue in the future!