# Using Spyder + Jupyter notebook, nothing is shown

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, spyder

I mean to use Spyder + Jupyter under Ubuntu 22.04LTS.
I have created a virtualenv (no Anaconda), and there I installed jupyter and launched spyder, following roughly [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-jupyter-notebook-with-python-3-on-ubuntu-18-04):

```
virtualenv spyder
source spyder/bin/activate
pip install jupyter spyder
pip install spyder-notebook
pip install jupyterlab
pip install notebook
pip install nbconvert
pip install voila
spyder &
```

But in spyder

```
No QCoreApplication instance found. Application patches not applied. You have to call load_stylesheet function after instantiation of QApplication to take effect. 
[W 2022-11-17 15:58:36.430 LabApp] 'password' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2022-11-17 15:58:36.430 LabApp] 'password' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[I 2022-11-17 15:58:36.436 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /home/santiago/Documents/soft-hard-ware/python/envs/spyder/spyder/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2022-11-17 15:58:36.436 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/user1/Documents/soft-hard-ware/python/envs/spyder/spyder/share/jupyter/lab
[I 15:58:36.525 SpyderNotebookServer] Serving notebooks from local directory: /tmp/spyder-user1/notebooks
[I 15:58:36.525 SpyderNotebookServer] Jupyter Notebook 6.5.2 is running at:
[I 15:58:36.525 SpyderNotebookServer] http://localhost:8888/?token=173564737e999d60998a362def73788fab59e6c93fe6e3f8
[I 15:58:36.525 SpyderNotebookServer]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=173564737e999d60998a362def73788fab59e6c93fe6e3f8
[I 15:58:36.525 SpyderNotebookServer] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 15:58:36.527 SpyderNotebookServer] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/user1/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-4275-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=173564737e999d60998a362def73788fab59e6c93fe6e3f8
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=173564737e999d60998a362def73788fab59e6c93fe6e3f8
```

The server is running, possibly with some functionality not properly set up, since this is what I see in firefox when loading file:///home/user1/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-4275-open.html

[image]

And in spyder when switching from the tabs at the bottom from *Editor* to *Notebook*, I don-t see anything, no possibility of entering code or else, either if I select *New Notebook* or I open an existing notebook from the three lines menu at the top right.

How can I get spyder to work with notebooks?

**Related**:

1. https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10608
2. https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/15163
3. [Spyder 5 No QCoreApplication instance found. Application patches not applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66979095/spyder-5-no-qcoreapplication-instance-found-application-patches-not-applied)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, and after a few days of trying to solve it, I finally found the solution based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74428737/21105946

So before running Spyder, it is sufficient to run this command:

```
export QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--no-sandbox"
```

Comment: Will check and post feedback. Thanks!